# Reuse DataTable in ButtonClick which is already open in form load

Tags: c#, winforms

I have open VFP dbf file from formload got the data into data table and
this also in gridview, I want to use this data result in another button click
How can I call that same data in  button click,I am new to this hope this maybe
very easy for some , Please help me.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataTable YourResultSet = new DataTable();

  OleDbConnection yourConnectionHandler = new OleDbConnection(
            @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=I:\\Bestall\\T&AData.dbc");

  yourConnectionHandler.Open();

  if (yourConnectionHandler.State == ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    string mySQL = "select * from Findat";  // dbf table name

    OleDbCommand MyQuery = new OleDbCommand(mySQL, yourConnectionHandler);
    OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(MyQuery);

    DA.Fill(YourResultSet);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = YourResultSet.DefaultView;
    // yourConnectionHandler.Close();

  }
}
```

Comment: Move this line `DataTable YourResultSet = new DataTable();` outside the load event scope.

Comment: I think you'll need to rephrase this to make more sense, in the meantime, if you're not seeing any data present in the datagrid it's because you need to call dataGridView1.DataBind() on it after you assign the DataSource.

Comment: @cullimorer this looks like WinForms.  No DataBind.

Comment: LarsTech if they're using ASP.net then putting that outside the Load won't do anything as it will get cleared on postback.

Comment: @cullimorer Like I said, looks like WinForms.

Comment: @LarsTech ah yea true if it's WinForm the data will persist

Comment: Thanks Lars Tech and others, yes it's WinForms and grid is working,I just wanted use the result, moving DataTable YourResultSet = new DataTable(); outside the load helped.

Comment: You can access your `DataTable` without moving it outside of `Form_Load`. `DataGridView.DataSource` will still have reference to the same table. So in button click you can do: `var myDataTable = (DataTable)datagridview.DataSource;`